# How to keep text in center of the html section when changing the screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

I have implemented a simple web page with 2 sections. In each of this section there is text contains 2 lines. I would like to keep this text in center (margin left, top, right, bottom) in the section when changing the size of the screen (RWD). E.g. when I run this web page on the desktop the text in the section will be in center-center of the section and when I run this web page on the smartphone/tablet this text also be in the center of the section. Is it possible to do it? The code is below:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  height: 60vh;
}
section:nth-child(1) {
  background: white;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f2efef;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

  <section>
    John is happy.<br><br>
    Thank you.<br><br>
  </section>

  <section>
    Have a nice day.<br><br>
    Good luck.<br><br>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flexbox grid for block alignment.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
section {
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
section:nth-child(1) {
  background: white;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background: #f2efef;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

  <section>
    John is happy.<br><br>
    Thank you.<br><br>
  </section>

  <section>
    Have a nice day.<br><br>
    Good luck.<br><br>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you.

in the CSS file you can use the following ways,

```
section {
  text-align:center;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

/* or */

```
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60vh;
}
```